# Refactor two recursive functions into one

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have two recursions. Is is possible to refactor them into one? `Requester.update` and `Requester.delete` return a promise, and I guess the main problem is the parameters that they receive, and I do not want to change them.

```
var tobeDeleted = [];
var tobeUpdated = [];

function calc1(node, original) {
    tobeUpdated.push(Requester.update(node["tag_id"], node));
    if (node.nodes.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    _.each(node.nodes, function(x) {
        x.hasPublish = original.hasPublish;
        x.hasInbox = original.hasInbox;
        x.hasMetrics = original.hasMetrics;
        calc1(x, original);
    });
}

calc1(tag, tag);

function calc2(node) {
    tobeDeleted.push(Requester.delete(node["tag_id"]));
    if (node.nodes.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    _.each(node.nodes, function(x) {
       calc2(x);
    });
}

calc2(tag);
```